# Restlet Java Framework - does Client need to be closed in some way?

Tags: restlet

I've just inherited some code that uses the Restlet framework - must admit I'd never even heard of it until now.

The pattern seems to be to do:

```
Request request = new Request(method, uri);
Client client = new Client(protocols);
Response response = client.handle(request);
```

but when I was debugging the code, I noticed quite a few daemon threads running. Is that normal? Should the code be closing the Client or something similar?

Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 2):

You should call `client.stop()` when you are done.

Comment: Thank you. I notice that the code does not call client.start() - is that done implicitly?

Comment: Yes, start() is implicit on first call. It can be called manually for warm-up purpose.

Comment: @JeromeLouvel: Is it required to call client.stop()? I can not find any reference in the documentation or book about calling stop()